# ERROR: Could not build wheels for hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I'm trying to install embeddinghub on mac (tried `pip3 install embeddinghub` and `pip3 install pandas embeddinghub protobuf`), but I get the same error saying "`could not build wheels for hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`." I can't find any solutions regarding hnswlib. I've tried a lot of solutions regarding PEP517 and building wheels for other things, but none of the solutions helped. Here's the full error:

**Error**

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.5.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (10.8 MB)
Collecting embeddinghub
  Using cached embeddinghub-0.0.1.post12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf
  Using cached protobuf-4.21.7-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (484 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1
  Using cached pytz-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (500 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.21.0
  Using cached numpy-1.23.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (13.3 MB)
Collecting grpcio==1.40.0
  Using cached grpcio-1.40.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_10_universal2.whl
Collecting hnswlib==0.5.2
  Using cached hnswlib-0.5.2.tar.gz (29 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.21.0
  Using cached numpy-1.21.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_universal2.whl
Collecting six==1.16.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: hnswlib
  Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/3h
      creating var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn
      creating var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/s/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c /var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T/tmp5hthbs8k.cpp -o var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T/tmp5hthbs8k.o -std=c++14
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/s/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c /var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T/tmpipibvgip.cpp -o var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T/tmpipibvgip.o -fvisibility=hidden
      building 'hnswlib' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/python_bindings
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/private/var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-hhht57g1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/private/var/folders/3h/0w98c6q56bl4x4c2qm31np_c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-hhht57g1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I./hnswlib/ -I/Users/s/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c ./python_bindings/bindings.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/./python_bindings/bindings.o -O3 -march=native -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -DVERSION_INFO=\"0.5.2\" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hnswlib
Failed to build hnswlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 53):

If you're using macOS, try setting an environment variable:

```
export HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1
```

And then retry...

Comment: This works for Apple MacBook Pro (2.9 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7) Ventura 13.1

Comment: Also worked for me on 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9 MacBook Pro Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: This works for me as well on 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro Ventura 13.4

Comment: This does NOT work on WSL Ubuntu

Comment: Worked for me on an M1 Macbook Air, TY :)

Comment: This did not work for me while trying to build localGPT. I get the same error message. 2.6 GHz i7 MacBook Pro

Comment: I ran this on Terminal in Apple MacBook Pro and it worked

Comment: add its only for mac.

Answer (score 52):

I have faced similar issue on Windows OS, while doing `pip install chromadb==0.3.22`.

To Resolve this issue,

You need to download https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ first.

Next, navigate to "**Individual components**", find these two

[image]

and Windows 10 SDK

[image]

source: https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/189#issuecomment-1454418844

Comment: Thanks for your support. I used this solution to solve privateGPT installation.

Comment: This was the solution for me, Thanks!

Comment: how did you figure out this solution? Amazing...

Comment: I'm baffled as to how this was even possible to figure out

Comment: trial and error method!

Comment: Nice! Thanks!  That worked.  It looked different for me, I had a pretty gui with different options than you had.   I just pretty much installed everything, most looked useful anyways and I got the space.

Comment: for windows 11 i had used @quantum-prophet answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791289/9024526 and it's worked

Answer (score 16):

In Ubuntu, these commands solved this problem, perhaps a Mac alternative could be useful too:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Comment: This did not fix it for me with WSL Ubuntu

Comment: Fixed the problem in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: fixed in WSL Ubuntu for me

Comment: Fixed the problem in Ubuntu 22.04 while trying to install ChromaDB

Comment: This only works for the default Python installation. See @Fahad Nadeem's answer if you are using other Python versions.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 20 and above, install dev tools and build essentials for Python version you're working with:

For Python3.10:

```
sudo apt install python3.10-dev && sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

For Python3.11:

```
sudo apt install python3.11-dev && sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok got it.... so a long winded solution for my use case but here it goes similar to one above:

1. download https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
2. navigate to "Individual components", find select those that were called out above by someone else:

[image]

and

[image]

3. finish the install
4. reboot computer
5. Then did a !pip install chromadb==0.3.26 selecting this specific version which worked for me. I do not think the most current one will work at this time, though I could be wrong.

Solutions I tried but didn't work for me, however worked for others:

1. !pip install wheel
2. !pip install --upgrade setuptools

Answer (score 2):

*This worked for me*

Install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools on your system. You can download and install it from the official Microsoft website: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/.

Answer (score 1):

```
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

It looks like the problem is caused by the clang compiler, which did not support the flag `-march=native` previously.

The following commit added support of the flag, and you may need to install the latest Xcode for it.

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/fcca10c69aaab539962d10fcc59a5f074b73b0de

Answer (score 1):

Downgraded Python to 3.10.10

```
export HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1 
pip install HNSWLIB
```

Answer (score 1):

if you using windows, try `set HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34676185)

Answer (score 0):

Clang compiler is not found.
check c/c++ version `clang -v`. if not found

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me, what did work for me in the end was using Anaconda to do the build rather than VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, install GCC. It should work.

```
brew info gcc
brew install gcc
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I also encoutered this problem when installing lang chain package to my Windows devices. I have download microsoft visual studio before, and I figured that you can just run the microsoft visual studio before you install, it will then work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac you can install/update xcode dev tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of Visual Studio actually, i was trying to install hnswlib and to built the wheel for hnswlib, it requires the Visual studio 2022, so i upgraded, but the code written in python was not including the headers for ucrt from Windows 10 toolkit SDK. So there was no way to change the python code to include the library and also its not a good idea to change the system level files of python to include this :"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt".

So the best solution i found is, to install the package using conda :

1. Install conda using Anaconda or miniconda if you dont have one
2. Create a conda virtual environment : `conda create -n localgpt python==3.10.0`.
3. install the hnswlib package first from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/hnswlib) : `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/hnswlib`.
4. Now install the requirements for your project using pip : `pip install -r requirements.txt`
   This should work fine, as packages form conda-forge dont build the wheels on your system.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, without having "Microsoft Visual C++" installed below command worked :

```
conda activate your_env_name
conda install -c conda-forge chromadb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue on Windows OS, To resolve this

1. Download built tools : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
2. Open it and In Workloads select "Desktop development with C++" click install
3. Restart your Python kernel
4. !pip install chromadb==0.3.25

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, I downloaded Xcode and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using poetry version 1.6.1. It worked for me