# Why does adding chromadb in requirements.txt cause failure in Azure deployment

Tags: azure, deployment

I am deploying a smart langchain python chatbot on Azure webapp services. I forgot to add chromadb in my requirements.txt file in the beginning, I was successful in building and deploying then. But when I add chromadb in the txt file, the build was great but it fails to deploy showing this error

```
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/ffa6200f-ed27-47d4-b8a3-e502d83f86d6.zip (0.93 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

This is not the case of disconnecting the app service because it did not work.
The deployment is only successful if I remove chromadb, but then ofcourse my app does not work because it needs chromadb to work.

How can I handle this?
I am a complete beginner in programming and deploying, any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known limitation on **chromadb**, Refer this [**Github issue**](https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/250) and [**SO thread answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969269/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-hnswlib-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec).
I added **chromadb** in my **requirements.txt**

```
Django

whitenoise

chromadb
```

And in-order for chromadb to work, I created Azure web app with Python version 3.8 and the deployment of Web app with chromadb in requirements.txt was successful, Refer below:-

[image]

***Deployed the web app via VS code app service extension and using Deploy to Web app button. The chromadb got installed successfully in web app with Python 3.8 version.***

[image]

**Deployment successful:-**

[image]

Web app [**reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=django,windows,azure-cli,vscode-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli)

[image]

I ***SSH'd into my Web app and tried accessing requirements.txt file the chromadb was available***, Refer below:-

```bash
ls
vi requirements.txt
```

[image]

[image]